# find password character input at SecurityController in symfony

Tags: symfony, passwords, find

i am new in symfony2 i want to access to username and password input character  in LoginAction at SecurityController

in this section i can get the last username

```
 $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
```

but i want the last password too.
how can i get the last password input ?

Comment: You can not (easily). You'd have to write a custom security listener. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it in the UserTokenProvider with

`$token->getCredentials()` in the function authenticateToken funtion

Comment: i want to get password when username and password is wrong